# How do I view the animation keys for my rgb node?

Tags: animation, materials, keyframes, color, timeline

[image: he]

As you can see I have animated the color property but I am not able to see it on my timeline.
How do I make it happen, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Oh I figured it out by clicking on the rgb node that changes the color. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select both the object and the node, or, in the *Dope Sheet*, disable the *Only Show Selected* option (and you'll see all the keyframes of your scene):

[image]